# How can I retrieve permission levels for site and list using powershell?

Tags: 2007, powershell, permissions

Sharepoint 2007 Powershell.
I have a powershell script that checks the permissions of a 2007 site collection and outputs it to an xml file.  The script is taken and modified from here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/04/24/the-power-of-powershell-and-sharepoint-enumerating-sharepoint-permissions-and.aspx

I wish to grab which permission *level* is applied to the site or list.  In 2010 this would be easier by using the RoleDefinitions property, but that property is not avaliable in 2007 as I understand it.  below is the relevant code I am attempting to modify.  It uses the "web.Permissions" property which I don't know much about unfortunately.  Can I write a function, pass it a site or list and a 'permission', and determine which level of access the group or user has to the site or list?

```
function DetermineUserAccess #-web <SPWeb> -depth <int>
{
  write-host "Determining User Access...$1"

  [string]$spaceBuffer = DetermineSpaceBuffer $args[1]

  #START SHAREPOINT GROUPS ENTITY
  Write-Output "$spaceBuffer<SPGroups>" | Out-File $OutFile -append

  foreach($perm in $args[0].Permissions)
  {
    write-output($perm.XML) | Out-file permxml.xml -append
    #CHECK IF MEMBER IS AN ACTIVE DIRECTORY ENTRY OR SHAREPOINT GROUP
    if($perm.XML.Contains('MemberIsUser="True"') -eq "True")
    {
      DisplayADEntry $perm.Member ($args[1] + 1)
    }
    #IS A SHAREPOINT GROUP
    else
    {
      $outputText = "$spaceBuffer$BUFFER_CHARS<SPGroup>" + ($perm.Member)
      Write-Output $outputText.Replace("&","&amp;") | Out-File $OutFile -append
      DisplaySPGroupMembers $perm.Member ($args[1] + 2)
      Write-Output "$spaceBuffer$BUFFER_CHARS</SPGroup>" | Out-File $OutFile -append
    }
  }
```